# Glue Spark write data one partition at time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Need help to understand how it works: I have 2 TB of data which I am writing using glue spark partition on a certain date column. I am using g2x with 40 workers nodes.

These are a few observations:

1. Job is writing one partition at one time i.e data for one day is loaded only. (Shouldn't it write data-parallel in multiple partitions)
2. It creates very small files within partitions.

For the above reason, writing data is very slow. Are there any settings that can be changed to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating very small files, you can use `coalesce(k)` where k is the number of partitions that you want to have, probably 40.

[More about coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce.html)